# Animation disappears on end LottieJS

Tags: javascript, function, animation, lottie

I have an animation build with `LottieJS` which loops like:

```
var lottieLogo = lottie.loadAnimation({
      container: document.getElementById('icon_logo'), // the dom element that will contain the animation
      renderer: 'svg',
      loop: true,
      autoplay: false,
      path: 'path-to-json'
    });
lottieLogo.play();
```

Then after animation is done I want to pause for 10 seconds like:

```
function logoAnimation() {
    lottieLogo.pause();
    setTimeout(
      function() 
         {
            lottieLogo.play();
         }, 10000);
}
lottieLogo.addEventListener('loopComplete', logoAnimation);
```

It works fine but the only problem is that the animation disappears for about 0.2 seconds every time it loads again. Anyone familiar with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you set `loop` to false it should give you the desired effect.